# REVTeX 4.1 table float option [H] pagebreak

Tags: tables, tabularx, revtex

According to [REVTeX 4.1](https://d22izw7byeupn1.cloudfront.net/files/revtex/apsguide4-1.pdf) guide, the float placement option [H] will enable LATEX to break a float across pages. How can I get it worked?

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\title{title}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{tables}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
8   &   5.53    &   11.14   &   7.84    \\
9   &   5.09    &   2.84    &   6.66    \\
10  &   5.13    &   9.02    &   5.91    \\
11  &   4.79    &   2.49    &   5.32    \\
12  &   4.07    &   6.35    &   4.82    \\
13  &   4.00    &   2.77    &   4.38    \\ 
14  &   3.40    &   4.28    &   3.98    \\ 
15  &   3.37    &   3.04    &   3.65    \\
16  &   3.05    &   3.09    &   3.37    \\
17  &   2.93    &   3.06    &   3.14    \\
18  &   2.78    &   2.52    &   2.94    \\
19  &   2.60    &   2.83    &   2.77    \\
20  &   2.52    &   2.25    &   2.62    \\
21  &   2.34    &   2.51    &   2.49    \\
22  &   2.28    &   2.11    &   2.37    \\
23  &   2.14    &   2.21    &   2.25    \\
24  &   2.07    &   2.00    &   2.15    \\
25  &   1.97    &   1.97    &   2.06    \\ 
26  &   1.90    &   1.89    &   1.98    \\
27  &   1.83    &   1.80    &   1.90    \\
28  &   1.76    &   1.77    &   1.83    \\
29  &   1.70    &   1.67    &   1.76    \\
30  &   1.64    &   1.65    &   1.70    \\
31  &   1.59    &   1.57    &   1.64    \\
32  &   1.54    &   1.54    &   1.59    \\
33  &   1.49    &   1.48    &   1.54    \\
34  &   1.45    &   1.44    &   1.49    \\
35  &   1.40    &   1.40    &   1.45    \\ 
36  &   1.37    &   1.36    &   1.40    \\
37  &   1.33    &   1.32    &   1.36    \\
38  &   1.29    &   1.28    &   1.33    \\ 
39  &   1.26    &   1.25    &   1.29    \\
40  &   1.23    &   1.22    &   1.26    \\
41  &   1.20    &   1.19    &   1.23    \\
42  &   1.17    &   1.16    &   1.20    \\
43  &   1.14    &   1.14    &   1.17    \\
44  &   1.11    &   1.11    &   1.14    \\
45  &   1.09    &   1.09    &   1.11    \\
46  &   1.07    &   1.06    &   1.09    \\
47  &   1.04    &   1.04    &   1.07    \\
48  &   1.02    &   1.02    &   1.04    \\
49  &   1.00    &   1.00    &   1.02    \\
50  &   0.98    &   0.98    &   1.00    \\
51  &   0.96    &   0.96    &   0.98    \\
52  &   0.94    &   0.94    &   0.96    \\
53  &   0.92    &   0.92    &   0.94    \\
54  &   0.91    &   0.90    &   0.92    \\
55  &   0.89    &   0.89    &   0.91    \\
56  &   0.87    &   0.87    &   0.89    \\
57  &   0.86    &   0.86    &   0.87    \\
58  &   0.84    &   0.84    &   0.86    \\
59  &   0.83    &   0.83    &   0.84    \\
60  &   0.82    &   0.81    &   0.83    \\
61  &   0.80    &   0.80    &   0.82    \\
62  &   0.79    &   0.79    &   0.80    \\
63  &   0.78    &   0.78    &   0.79    \\
64  &   0.76    &   0.76    &   0.78    \\
65  &   0.75    &   0.75    &   0.76    \\
66  &   0.74    &   0.74    &   0.75    \\
67  &   0.73    &   0.73    &   0.74    \\
68  &   0.72    &   0.72    &   0.73    \\
69  &   0.71    &   0.71    &   0.72    \\
70  &   0.70    &   0.70    &   0.71    \\
71  &   0.69    &   0.69    &   0.70    \\
72  &   0.68    &   0.68    &   0.69    \\
73  &   0.67    &   0.67    &   0.68    \\
74  &   0.66    &   0.66    &   0.67    \\
75  &   0.65    &   0.65    &   0.66    \\
76  &   0.64    &   0.64    &   0.65    \\
77  &   0.63    &   0.63    &   0.64    \\
78  &   0.63    &   0.63    &   0.64    \\
79  &   0.62    &   0.62    &   0.63    \\
80  &   0.61    &   0.61    &   0.62    \\
81  &   0.60    &   0.60    &   0.61    \\
82  &   0.60    &   0.60    &   0.60    \\
83  &   0.59    &   0.59    &   0.60    \\
84  &   0.58    &   0.58    &   0.59    \\
85  &   0.57    &   0.57    &   0.58    \\
86  &   0.57    &   0.57    &   0.58    \\
87  &   0.56    &   0.56    &   0.57    \\
88  &   0.56    &   0.55    &   0.56    \\
89  &   0.55    &   0.55    &   0.56    \\
90  &   0.54    &   0.54    &   0.55    \\
91  &   0.54    &   0.54    &   0.54    \\
92  &   0.53    &   0.53    &   0.54    \\
93  &   0.53    &   0.52    &   0.53    \\
94  &   0.52    &   0.52    &   0.53    \\
95  &   0.51    &   0.51    &   0.52    \\
96  &   0.51    &   0.51    &   0.51    \\
97  &   0.50    &   0.50    &   0.51    \\
98  &   0.50    &   0.50    &   0.50    \\
99  &   0.49    &   0.49    &   0.50    \\
100 &   0.49    &   0.49    &   0.49    
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, they messed up -- big time. This info is wrong.

Comment: The information is *utterly* wrong and they should know better. The `table` environment can *never* be split across pages.